# fetching a row in the middle of the table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT r.*, u.username 
FROM `reservation` AS r JOIN 
     `users` AS u 
WHERE u.id = r.user_id 
AND   DATE(r.bx_date) >= DATE('2012-08-22') 
AND   DATE(r.bx_date) <= DATE('2012-08-22') 
AND   r.status='1' 
ORDER BY r.id desc
```

Table reservation contains 500,000 records and bx_date varies from 2012-01-01 to 2013-01-01. 40,000 records in users table. bx_date is 'date' type.

With the query above if I tried a date like 2012-08-22, It takes 8 secs. But if I tried 2013-01-01 It takes like 1 sec.

What is the reason?

Comment: Was there any difference in the number of records for those two dates you mentioned? Also, do you want reindex the table and run the same queries to see if it was due to fragmentation?

Comment: Which indexes did you have on table?

Comment: noh ! same number of records. As indexes I have used ids of the both tables

Comment: `bx_date` should be indexed IMHO...

Comment: have done. But still no change here

Comment: could you provide the schema for reservation table, along with the indexes defined on it?

Comment: I think the reason can be that `DATE(r.bx_date) >= DATE('2013-01-01')` will return no record(which would be very fast) as there is no filtering. and also can you try by making a composite index on userid and bx_date.

Comment: the index should contain bx_date and user_id in that order and if required should be specified explicitly through a hint.

Comment: @AnkurMittal, Dasun has confirmed that count of records for both dates is same.

Comment: @Vikdor agreed but when date is '2012-08-22' there are two filtering conditions(without index on bx_date), in the latter case there is effectively only one filetring.

Comment: Show the results of EXPLAIN <your query> for both cases.

Comment: @Vikdor: concur on indexing (+1; but not sure about the hint; the optimizer should see it by itself, I think, the join is straightforward). I have also added `status`, so that this one check can be done with faster.

Comment: @Iserni, ideally the optimizer should pick the appropriate index, but we had problems with SQLServer where it was opting for the ones that contained the primary key and so, we started hinting the index explicitly :). BTW, adding status was a good thought as that would completely limit the filtering to the index itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is improper indexing or index maintenance.

You should have an index such as:

```
CREATE INDEX reservation_ndx ON reservation
    (status, bx_date, user_id)
```

Also, if using InnoDB, try running

```
ANALYZE TABLE reservation;
```

in order to let the system update the table demographics.

Another possible (but IMHO not so likely) cause could be table partitioning:

```
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html
```

seeing as `reservation` is probably filled incrementally with time.

**update**: I hadn't mentioned the obvious cause, that one query might return one million records and the other query fail instantly, but if you don't know what the SQL results are (maybe you're just running 'blind' benchmarks and only check execution time), that also might be a possibility. (*update on update: I just read that both queries return the same number of rows. This cause is then excluded*)

Comment: I think adding indexes will fix the problem. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Well, let me know. Also try ANALYZE first, I'm really curious as to the benefits in such a 'macroscopic' case.

Answer (score 0):

Data is available in your table reservation upto today('2012-08-22') . But, no data to be found for 2013. Data availability makes this change.

Comment: There are data up to 2013-01-01